# Python: Why does my "variable += 1" not work as expected?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, operators

```
username = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
usernamelist = []
next = 0
while len(username) > 0:
    for part in accumulate(username):
        usernamelist.append(part)
    next += 1
    username = username[next:]
print(usernamelist)
```

I'm trying to output every part of the username (like "n", "ne", "nee", ... , "neelkamath@gmail.com", "e", "ee", ... , "eelkamath@gmail.com" etc.) but instead of going from "n" to "neelkamath@gmail.com" *and then* from "e" to "eelkamath@gmail.com" *and then* from "e" to "elkamath@gmail.com"; it skips an extra **one** letter each time, despite me only adding *1* to "next". It goes from "n" to "e" (one letter ahead, as it's supposed to) to "l" (2 letters ahead) to "m" (3 letters ahead) and so on. Am I placing the `next += 1`
in an incorrect position?

Comment: You may want to change the email address for something more generic. 

Comment: @JacquesGaudin it's alright, it's not a real email (it's a deleted address)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to increment `next` if you want to remove one character for each iteration of the while loop:

```
username = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
usernamelist = []
while len(username) > 0:
    for part in accumulate(username):
        usernamelist.append(part)
    username = username[1:]
print(usernamelist)
```

By incrementing `next` you increment the number of characters to be skipped:

At first iteration: after `username = username[1:]` `username` is `"eelkamath@gmail.com"`

At second iteration: after `username = username[1:]` `username` is `"elkamath@gmail.com"` but after `username = username[2:]` `username` is `"lkamath@gmail.com"`

Answer (score 2):

You would like to use a for-loop instead:

```
username = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
usernamelist = []
for start in range(len(username)):
    usernamelist.extend(accumulate(username[start:]))
print(usernamelist)
```

But `accumulate` is not very efficient. For large strings, use slicing:

```
username = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
usernamelist = [
    username[s:e]
    for s, e in combinations(range(len(username)+1), 2)
]
print(usernamelist)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are modifying «username» *from an already modified value*.

To better understand this, think that the line:

```
username = username[next:]
```

is not picking a part of the original value (*neelkamath@gmail.com*), but from the already trimmed (in the previous loop). It's all about what's your reference for the next iteration.

This example may help:

```
from itertools import accumulate
username1 = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
username2 = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
usernamelist = []
next = 0
while len( username2 ) > 0:
    for part in accumulate( username2 ):
        usernamelist.append( part )
    next += 1
    username2 = username1[next:]
    print( username1 )
    print( username2 )
print(usernamelist)
```

Answer (score 0):

`a = "neelkamath@gmail.com"
for i in range(0, len(a) + 1):
        print a[:i]`

Output

`n
ne
nee
neel
neelk
neelka
neelkam
neelkama
neelkamat
neelkamath
neelkamath@
neelkamath@g
neelkamath@gm
neelkamath@gma
neelkamath@gmai
neelkamath@gmail
neelkamath@gmail.
neelkamath@gmail.c
neelkamath@gmail.co
neelkamath@gmail.com`

Comment: This is not the output required by the OP